# Solving Linear Diophantine Equation Systems in C++

Tags: c++, diophantine

For my research I'm confronted with a system of linear diophantine equations.

I found several research papers on the topic but before I start to create
a solver myself, I would like to know if one does know of a (lightweight)
C++ math library, which solves such a system.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try to use Octave embedded:

http://octave.sourceforge.net/docs.html